# how to convert longitude and altitude to a grid with equal(nearly) area on the Earth sphere in Matlab or C/C++?

Tags: c, matlab, math, area

The range of longitude and latitude of Earth sphere are [-180, 180] and [-90, 90] respectively. I want to get equal area grids by 0.5 deg * 0.5 deg (area around the equator).
As the distortion increased when approaching the polar points. The grid should have the same latitude range but different longitude range.

How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you ask got, if interpreted literally, is impossible for three reasons. One, the area of the surface of a perfect sphere is about 82506.97413 times the area of a portion 30' (thirty seconds, or half a degree) by 30' at the equator. Since that is not an integer, you cannot partition the surface into a whole number of regions of that size. Two, if you constrain the latitude span to be equal, then the rings at different latitudes must have different numbers of segments, so you cannot make a grid. The edges of segments in different rings cannot coincide. Three, the Earth is not a perfect sphere, and regions of equal area on a sphere will not map to equal areas on the Earth. Imperfections in the Earth would prevent us from knowing the area of each region (and those areas would change as the surface changes).

Supposing that what you actually want is an approximate solution that is not a grid, I suggest you examine the [Google search results for “partition sphere into equal areas“](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=partition+sphere+into+equal+areas&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). One of the top results is [this paper](http://www.academia.edu/1449144/A_partition_of_the_unit_sphere_into_regions_of_equal_area_and_small_diameter), in which Figure 1.1 appears to show a sphere that has been partitioned into regions of similar, possibly equal, latitude span but different longitude spans. Another result is [this page](http://eqsp.sourceforge.net/), which is a Matlab package for exploring sphere partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put equal area tiles on the earth's surface with fixed extent like the mirrors on a disco ball.

So if you start at the Equator with a 0.5deg*0.5deg tile, your next tile to the north or south would have a longitude extent of 0.5deg/cos(0.5deg) to have the same area, so slightly above 0.5deg.
With that tile you cannot fill the full circle with an integer number of tiles.

Ending at the pole your tile longitude extent would be 0.5deg/cos(89.5deg) = 59,29..deg which also does not fit exactly into 360degs.

If you decrease the size of your tiles you might have an acceptable small error but yet no real "grid" because coming to the poles there will always be less tiles than at the Equator..

Maybe something like "equal area map projection" might help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equal-area

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions here (formulas in R):

```
lat<-seq(-89.75,89.75,by=0.5)
```

## Formula 1, based on the area of a grid point in the equator (111.11km2).

```
r<-(111*10^3*0.5)*(111*10^3*0.5)*cos(lat*pi/180)
```

## Formula 2, based on the radius of the Earth.

```
ER<-6371*1000
r2<-(ER^2)*(0.5*pi/180)^2*cos(lat*pi/180)
```